# Spark Structured Streaming program that reads from non-empty Kafka topic (starting from earliest) triggers batches locally, but not on EMR cluster

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, amazon-emr, spark-structured-streaming

We are running into a problem where -- for one of our applications --
we don't see any evidences of batches being processed in the Structured
Streaming tab of the Spark UI.

I have written a small program (below) to reproduce the issue.
A self-contained project that allows you to build the app, along with scripts that facilitate upload to AWS, and details on how to run and reproduce the issue can be found here: https://github.com/buildlackey/spark-struct-streaming-metrics-missing-on-aws (The github version of the app is a slightly evolved version of what is presented below, but it illustrates the problem of  Spark streaming metrics not showing up.)

The program can be  run 'locally' -- on  someones' laptop in local[*] mode  (say with a dockerized Kafka instance),
or on an EMR cluster.   For local mode operation you invoke the main method with 'localTest' as the first
argument.

In our case, when we run on the EMR cluster, pointing to a topic
where we know there are many data records (we read from 'earliest'), we
see that THERE ARE INDEED NO BATCHES PROCESSED -- on the cluster for some reason...

In the local[*] case we CAN see batches processed.
To capture evidence of this i wrote a forEachBatch handler that simply does a
toLocalIterator.asScala.toList.mkString("\n") on the Dataset of each batch,  and then dumps the
resultant string to a file.   Running locally.. i see evidence of the
captured records in the temporary  file.  HOWEVER, when I run  on
the cluster and i ssh into one of the executors i see NO SUCH
files.  I also checked the master node.... no files matching the pattern '*Missing*'
So... batches are not triggering on the cluster.  Our kakfa has plenty of data and
when running on the cluster the logs show we are churning through messages at increasing offsets:

```
21/12/16 05:15:21 DEBUG KafkaDataConsumer: Get spark-kafka-source-blah topic.foo.event-18 nextOffset 4596542913 requested 4596542913
21/12/16 05:15:21 DEBUG KafkaDataConsumer: Get spark-kafka-source-blah topic.foo.event-18 nextOffset 4596542914 requested 4596542914
```

Note to get the logs we are using:

```
yarn yarn logs --applicationId <appId>
```

which should get both driver and executor logs for the entire run (when app terminates)

Now, in the local[*] case we CAN see batches processed. The evidence is that we see a file whose name
is matching the pattern '*Missing*' in our tmp folder.

I am including my simple demo program below.  If you can spot the issue and clue us in, I'd be very grateful !

```
// Please forgive the busy code.. i stripped this down from a much larger system....
import com.typesafe.scalalogging.StrictLogging
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.{OutputMode, Trigger}
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Dataset, SparkSession}
import java.io.File
import java.util
import scala.collection.JavaConverters.asScalaIteratorConverter
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration

object AwsSupportCaseFailsToYieldLogs extends StrictLogging {
  case class KafkaEvent(fooMsgKey: Array[Byte],
                        fooMsg: Array[Byte],
                        topic: String,
                        partition: String,
                        offset: String) extends Serializable

  case class SparkSessionConfig(appName: String, master: String) {
    def sessionBuilder(): SparkSession.Builder = {
      val builder = SparkSession.builder
      builder.master(master)
      builder
    }
  }

  case class KafkaConfig(kafkaBootstrapServers: String, kafkaTopic: String, kafkaStartingOffsets: String)
    def sessionFactory: (SparkSessionConfig) => SparkSession = {
      (sparkSessionConfig) => {
        sparkSessionConfig.sessionBuilder().getOrCreate()
      }
    }

    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
      val (sparkSessionConfig, kafkaConfig) =
        if (args.length >= 1 && args(0) == "localTest") {
          getLocalTestConfiguration
        } else {
          getRunOnClusterConfiguration
        }

      val spark: SparkSession = sessionFactory(sparkSessionConfig)

      spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

      import spark.implicits._

      val dataSetOfKafkaEvent: Dataset[KafkaEvent] = spark.readStream.
        format("kafka").
        option("subscribe", kafkaConfig.kafkaTopic).
        option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafkaConfig.kafkaBootstrapServers).
        option("startingOffsets", kafkaConfig.kafkaStartingOffsets).
        load.
        select(
          $"key" cast "binary",
          $"value" cast "binary",
          $"topic",
          $"partition" cast "string",
          $"offset" cast "string").map { row =>

        KafkaEvent(
          row.getAs[Array[Byte]](0),
          row.getAs[Array[Byte]](1),
          row.getAs[String](2),
          row.getAs[String](3),
          row.getAs[String](4))
      }

      val initDF = dataSetOfKafkaEvent.map { item: KafkaEvent => item.toString }
      val function: (Dataset[String], Long) => Unit =
        (dataSetOfString, batchId) => {
          val iter: util.Iterator[String] = dataSetOfString.toLocalIterator()

          val lines  = iter.asScala.toList.mkString("\n")
          val outfile = writeStringToTmpFile(lines)
          println(s"writing to file: ${outfile.getAbsolutePath}")
          logger.error(s"writing to file: ${outfile.getAbsolutePath} /  $lines")
        }
      val trigger = Trigger.ProcessingTime(Duration("1 second"))

      initDF.writeStream
        .foreachBatch(function)
        .trigger(trigger)
        .outputMode("append")
        .start
        .awaitTermination()
    }

    private def getLocalTestConfiguration: (SparkSessionConfig, KafkaConfig) = {
      val sparkSessionConfig: SparkSessionConfig =
        SparkSessionConfig(master = "local[*]", appName = "dummy2")
      val kafkaConfig: KafkaConfig =
        KafkaConfig(
          kafkaBootstrapServers = "localhost:9092",
          kafkaTopic = "test-topic",
          kafkaStartingOffsets = "earliest")
      (sparkSessionConfig, kafkaConfig)
    }

    private def getRunOnClusterConfiguration = {
      val sparkSessionConfig: SparkSessionConfig = SparkSessionConfig(master = "yarn", appName = "AwsSupportCase")
      val kafkaConfig: KafkaConfig =
        KafkaConfig(
          kafkaBootstrapServers= "kafka.foo.bar.broker:9092",         //  TODO - change this for kafka on your EMR cluster.
          kafkaTopic= "mongo.bongo.event",                            //  TODO - change this for kafka on your EMR cluster.
          kafkaStartingOffsets = "earliest")
      (sparkSessionConfig, kafkaConfig)
    }

  def writeStringFile(string: String, file: File): File = {
    java.nio.file.Files.write(java.nio.file.Paths.get(file.getAbsolutePath), string.getBytes).toFile
  }

  def writeStringToTmpFile(string: String, deleteOnExit: Boolean = false): File = {
    val file: File = File.createTempFile("streamingConsoleMissing", "sad")
    if (deleteOnExit) {
      file.delete()
    }
    writeStringFile(string, file)
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to enable debug/trace level logging (maybe starting with Kafka client classes) to see if there'd be any clues?

Comment: i've been seeing some strangeness with yarn logs that might be simply due to cock-pit error.. But yes indeed..   i've turned on logging in org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming(TRACE).. but i am not seeing the progress metrics that i'd expect would be there.  I am going to try to repro what i have in my github project on a spark stand-alone cluster (in docker) .. i understand those better than AWS/EMR setup

Comment: Re: my comment above.. one reason i did not see the expected msg in the log on progress for each batch was because my batch never completed !  (even though work was being done)

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered similar issue, maxOffsetsPerTrigger would fix the issue. Actually, it's not issue.

1. All logs and metrics per batch are only printed or showing after
   finish of this batch. That's the reason  why you can't see the job make
   progress.
2. If maxOffsetsPerTrigger can't solve the issue, you could try to consume from latest offset to confirm the procssing logic is correct.

Comment: It does seem to be maxOffsets !    we are still drilling in.

Comment: warren i am very sorry the bounty expired before i was able to award it to you.  if you can figure out how to resurrect it, i'd be glad to ask you get it, since you were helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This is a provisional answer. One of our team members has a theory that looks pretty likely.  Here it is: Batches ARE getting processed (this is demonstrated better by the version of the program I linked to on github), but we are thinking that since there is so much backed up in the topic on our cluster that the processing (from earliest) of the first batch takes a very long time, hence when looking at the cluster we see zero batches processed... even though there is clearly work being done.      It might be that the solution is to use maxOffsetsPerTrigger to gate the amount of incoming traffic (when starting from earliest and working w/ a topic that has huge volumes of data).  We are working on confirming this.